# Prove that $M_{n , K} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(X_{i} - \bar{X_{n}})^{K} \ne \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} X_{i}^{K} - \bar{X_{n}}^{K}$ for k > 2

Tags: statistics, summation, random-variables

Suppose that $X_{1} , X_{2} ... X_{n}$ are i.i.d with expected value $EX_{i} = \mu$ and let $\bar{X_{n}}$ be the sample average of the random variables.

Im trying to prove that:

$M_{n , k} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n}{(X_{i} - \bar{X_{n}})}^{k} \ne \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n}X_{i}^k - \bar{X_{n}}^{k}$

Where $M_{n , k} $ is the kth central moment.

I know that for k = 2:

$M_{n , 2} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(X_{i} - \bar{X_{n}})^{2} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} X_{i}^{2} - \bar{X_{n}}^{2}$

How do I that for the case k > 2 that these two terms are not equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true for $k\gt 2$:

For example with $n=2$ and $x_1=1,x_2=3$, you get $\bar x=2$, so for $k=3$:

- $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n}{(x_{i} - \bar{x})}^{3} = \frac12(-1+1)=0$
- $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n}x_{i}^3 - \bar{x}^{3}=\frac12(1+27)-2^3= 14-8=6$